# Particle number conservation in matrix product state

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-information, symmetry, computational-physics, tensor-network

I've been trying to understand how particle number conservation is enforced in matrix product state algorithms. As far as I understand, if the Hamiltonian commutes with the number operator, you can exploit the U(1) symmetry by asserting certain block diagonal structures in your tensors, and essentially attach the current particle number to your tensor.

Now a very simple problem, if I have a fermionic Hubbard model at half-filling, then the algorithm states that the matrix on the first site only has dimension 1 + 1, since you can have either 0 or 1 particles, and both have a 1D irrep. By this logic, matrix of site 2 has dimension 1 + 2 + 1, site 3 has 1 + 3 + 3 + 1, and so on and so forth. Eventually it seems the dimension of the tensors still blow up exponentially (it's a combinatorics problem) (SVD will help but still exponential). Now you can exploit the particle-hole symmetry on the other end, which reduces the potential tensor dimension,  but only by its square root (you effectively cut the chain in half)

My question is then this seems to defeat the whole point of having a MPS that doesn't blow up exponentially as something like exact diagonalization. If you can point out what is wrong/incomplete with this logic it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with symmetries? The same will happen if you don't impose them.

Comment: Hmm could you elaborate what you mean by 'the same'? What confused me is that for example in ED, if I have a L-site N-particle (spinless fermionic) system, I need a (L choose N) * (L choose N) matrix which is obvious. So far what I read about MPS is that if you want to impose that in MPS your tensors still blow up exponentially in a similar way. I'm not sure if I understand that correctly that's why I was asking

Comment: Indeed, if you want to describe any state in the full many-body Hilbert space exactly, the number of parameters in *any* method will blow up exponentially. My point is that this exponential blow-up for MPS will also happen when you do not impose symmetries. So the way your question is written, it focuses on something which is not at all the point.

Comment: Ah ok I see. Sorry I'm definitely not an expert on this topic, the symmetry part does seem redundant.
Now maybe I will reformulate my question. You made a good point about need a exponentially large parameter space to arbitrarily approach a many-body state, then how does one practically implement particle number conservation in MPS, for example? As opposed to using a (L choose N) square matrix in ED, which guarantees PN conservation, in MPS I suppose that information is kept in the block diagonal structure of your tensors? But as I understand, these tensors also blow up exponentially

Comment: So even if I am to approximate this, by SVD and throwing the smaller singular values, doesn't the initial SVD still take exponential time?

Comment: That is, I know you could indeed attach the particle number to your tensor, so that the MPS has structure like 0 -> ... -> N, where N is your final particle number. However, since each site can contribute either 0 or 1, it seems to me there are O( L choose N) possible combinations especially in the middle. Do we only consider the distinct particle number and not their multiplicity?

Answer (score 1):

Tensor networks (with restricted maximum bond dimensions) are entanglement-limited ansatze. They are useful for the tiny subregion of Hilbert space with some sort of area-law (rather than volume-law) entanglement scaling. Luckily, most ground states of local models also lie in this tiny subregion of Hilbert space. Like any other method, it is futile to try to losslessly represent arbitrary states in a high-dimensional Hilbert space, even when exploiting symmetries.

Tensor networks are entanglement-limited because they are bond-dimension limited. Memory use and runtime of many algorithms scales with large polynomial powers in the bond dimension. Exploiting symmetries (as you have correctly pointed out) can let you find block-diagonal structures, reducing the bond dimension required to represent the same state. While you are still restricted to area-law states, even cutting the required bond dimension in half is a big speedup in practice.